# Javascript error on line 946275090 in IE?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I am getting an error only on IE saying object does not support method but the line it is saying is somewhere around 946275090 (I know IE is off on line numbers but not usually this off).  I could of swore this type of error had a specific meaning but I for the life of me can't remember.  Does it mean something specific when IE return the error on a line number ridiculously large like this?

Comment: Wait, are you sure you *don't* have a billion line javascript file hiding somewhere? :)

Comment: saying manage is not a method of the object (manage not even being in the javascript, manage is part of the url)

Comment: @ryanzec - Well obviously some code is calling `manage` on an object that doesn't have that method. Can you show us the code?

Comment: @ChaosPandion Can't really show you the code but the error goes away when I get rid of this line:

delete window.disabled_button

is using delete in IE not good?

Comment: @ryanzec - There are very few good reasons to use `delete`. What's your reason?

Comment: @ChoasPandion I agree (I have yet to find the need to use it myself), this is existing code I am working with.  I just modified it to window.disabled_button = undefined; and that works in IE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without looking at the rest of the code it's hard (impossible?) to tell for sure what's wrong.

That said, I'd really recommend running your code through [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/), to help you identify any potential problems.  I believe that IE has some issues (i.e. not standards compliant) when it comes to `delete` operator.  So, if you feel that your code base is too large to test with JSLint, I'd suggest at least isolating and testing the sections using `delete`.

If you're interested in some extra reading, "[Finding Improper JavaScript Globals](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/2/Finding-Improper-JavaScript-Globals)" is a great article looking at `declared`, `implied` and `window` globals, which covers how they handle being deleted (among other things).